# Pentaho + MongoDB input step error : com.mongodb.MongoException$CursorNotFound

Tags: linux, mongodb, cursor, pentaho

I have a extraction that have a transformation : to get data from mongoDB,format it properly and write to mysql database.

I tried table output and mysql bulk load steps to data output.

Please have a look on the below issue ..

```
"ERROR [org.pentaho.di] MongoDB Input - com.mongodb.MongoException$CursorNotFound: cursor not found on server
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$Result.init(DBApiLayer.java:371)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$Result._advance(DBApiLayer.java:418)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$Result.hasNext(DBApiLayer.java:400)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:489)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:509)
at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.mongodbinput.MongoDbInput.processRow(MongoDbInput.java:61)
at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:40)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)"
```

I am getting this error when ever I am trying to fetch data from mongoDB by running the transformation from an extraction.
Please suggest what might have gone wrong.
It works fine for upto 12000 to 14000 records then abruptly completes ( with successful message)

I need to fetch data from MongoDB and put it into mysql database.

Our mongo database have a total of 2000000 records and it hardly works for 1% of the records.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

thanks
Priyabrata patnaik

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "abruptly completes ( with successful message)". Can you please describe what you are doing in more detail.

My guess is that the transformation is taking too long and the cursors are timing out in the meanwhile. I would be able to help you more if you could describe the problem more clearly.

Comment: I am running the extraction on a Pentho server.

Comment: I thought that this may be because of input output latency and hence changed the output step ( i tried with table output first and then mysql bulk loader)  but same error in both the cases.

Please suggest what might have gone wrong...
or any suggestion how to handle the data...

Basic requirement is to get data from mongoDB, format it properly and store it in mySql database.

Comment: I am running the extraction on a Pentho server.

I created an extraction and a transformation and deployed them on the pentaho server.
I used my pentaho user to run the transformation.

Comment: In the browser after around 30 minutes it shows action successful,
but actually it logs the above error in the pentaho logs.

and also it is not processing all the records, it processed nearly 12000 records and then logged the error and abruptly completed.

we have nearly 2000000 records to be processed, Please suggest what needs to be done.

Comment: How long does it take to process 1 document ?